# Show next and previous keys of an array with cycling

Tags: php, arrays, math

I'm sure you're gonna like it ;).

I need a function for building navigation for browsing pages in a book (where some pages could have been reaped apart and it should cycle back and forth); it should output links( as numbers) to the "next" and "previous" pages of the given page.

Function that will receive an array and a key on input should spit out the value of the given key of the array as well as a value of "next" and "previous" values. **However if the given key is the first key in the array it should output last key of an array as "previous". Likewise, if it receives the last key, it should output the first key as "next".**

Here's what I have so far:

```
$pages = array(5, 1, 6, 8);
sort($pages);

$selected = 1; // that's second key (value:5, next:6, previous:1)
// $selected = 3; // that's forth and a last key (value:8, should return next:1, previous:6)

$selected = key($pages)+$selected;

while ($pointer = current($pages)) {

if ($selected == key($pages) ) {
        echo $pointer." - current <br>";
    }
elseif($selected+1 == key($pages) ){
    echo $pointer." - next <br>";
}
elseif($selected-1 == key($pages) ){
    echo $pointer." - previous <br>";
}

else
    echo $pointer."<br>";

    next($pages);
}
```

THis should actually work (but without 'cycle awarness') - you can check quickly in http://writecodeonline.com/php/- if the description confuses you, **output of this code is quite self explanatory...**
I believe it's quite easy, but I'm out of ideas and it's 3 o'clock in the morning. Of course I need most simple solution, so ther could be some easier way, than the one I've chosen.

Comment: What do you mean with "cycling"? And about the output - how 6 is after 5 and 1 is before 5? What is the meaning of the order into array then?

Comment: Array could be passed unsorted, but that's solved with php sort(), so don't worry about that. Cycling means that links "next" and "previous" should work in cycle, like this (from the example in this sorted array): 1, 5 , 6 , 8 , [1 , 5 ,6, 8 ], 1 , 5 , 6 ,  and so on (so if you're on 8, next is 1, if you're on 1 previous is 8). I believe it's called "ring counter" in mechanics.

Comment: But It's still unclear to myself, what's the purpose of this? And how this is connected to books with scrapped pages? If 3rd and 4th pages are scrapped, then I'm going from 2 straight to 5? If you give me a real-life example or a straightforward scenario it will be a lot easier.

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought the book example would better(quicker) illustrate what I need. Real-life example is this: I have custom-built CMS. It shows categories and then products of given category. If you go to a particular product page you should have navigation for Next and Previous products in that category. Initial products can have numbers issued from 1 to 10, but if admin removes a product than it leave a gap in numeration (thus ripped apart pages in a book). Additionally navigation should work in rotation (as a "ring counter"), like I've wrote above. Does this makes things clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is solution of your problem. Tell me if it's doing what you want (Some checking if you're going out of array bounds will be good :) but let's stick to simplicity...):

```
/* This is from your code */
$pages = array(5, 1, 6, 8);
sort($pages);

$selected = 1; // that's second key (value:5, next:6, previous:1)
$selected = 3; // that's forth and a last key (value:8, should return next:1, previous:6)
/* ... */

$pages_count = count($pages);
$pages_ordered = array();
$pages_ordered["current"] = $pages[$selected];


foreach($pages as $order_number => $page)
{
    if($selected == 0) {
        $pages_ordered["previous"] = $pages[$pages_count - 1];
        $pages_ordered["next"] = $pages[$selected + 1];
    } elseif($selected == ($pages_count - 1)) {
        $pages_ordered["next"] = $pages[0];
        $pages_ordered["previous"] = $pages[$selected - 1];
    } else {
        $pages_ordered["next"] = $pages[$selected + 1];
        $pages_ordered["previous"] = $pages[$selected - 1]; 
    }
}

print_r($pages_ordered);
```

Comment: Thank you - nice and simple, plus "next" and "previous" can cycle thru all array now :). That's what T needed. It shows how helpless developer I am (sometimes, at least ;). Still I'm surpriesed a bit that such mechanism is so rare in other questions here and on the net, that it's not understood straight from the box and seems awkward to some...

Answer (score 1):

It really is pretty simple to be honest.

```
$pages = array(5, 1, 6, 8);
sort($pages);

//how many pages do we have 
$total = count($pages);

//replace with $_GET['page']; when ready
$requested_page = rand(0, ($total -1)); //$_GET['page'];

//the selected page 
$selected = $pages[$requested_page];

//if this isn't the first page
if($selected != $pages[0]):

    //get the previous page
    $prev = $requested_page-1;

    //standard issue
    echo '<a style="margin:0 15px;" href="myscript.php?page=', $pages[$prev] ,'"> Previous </a>';
endif;


//iterate each page
foreach($pages as $page):

    //a ternary operator to assign a class if this is the current page we're on or not
    $cls = ($page == $selected ) ? 'active' : false; //for your current page class

    //you don't need the style
    echo '<a class="', $cls ,'" href="myfile.php?page=', $page ,'">', $page ,'</a>';
endforeach;

//if this is not the last page
if(selected != $pages[$total]):

    //our next page
    $next = $requested_page+1;

    //standard issue
    echo '<a href="myscript.php?page=', $pages[$next] ,'"> Next </a>';
endif;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I think, this function does not cycle. Perhaps I've explained it not sufficiently. Links "next" and "previous" should work in cycle, like in the example in this sorted array : 1, 5 , 6 , 8 , [1 , 5 ,6, 8 ], 1 , 5 , 6 ,  and so on (I'll emphasize this part in my question)

Answer (score 0):

Try this function

```
function get_nav($arr,$current){
    while($nav = current($arr)){
      if(key($arr)==$current){
         $prev =prev($arr);
         empty($prev)?reset($arr):''; 
         next($arr);
         $r = current($arr);
         $next = next($arr); 
         prev($arr);
         return array('prev'=>$prev,'current'=>$r,'next'=>$next);
      }
      next($arr);
    }

    return FALSE;
}

$pages = array(5, 1, 6, 8);
sort($pages);

$selected = 0;
$res = get_nav($pages,$selected);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I think, this function does not cycle. Perhaps I've explained it not sufficiently. Links "next" and "previous" should work in cycle, like in the example in this sorted array : 1, 5 , 6 , 8 , [1 , 5 ,6, 8 ], 1 , 5 , 6 ,  and so on (I'll emphasize this part in my question)